# How to limit results from neo4j traversal with neography

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j, traversal, neography

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I turn to the wisdom of SO to get me over this bump :)

I'm using RoR 3.1.1 with the neography gem.

I currently have a neo4j graph of people nodes with relationships as "friends" connecting them.  Given a specific person's node, I'd like to page through results of their friends-of-friends (2nd degree nodes) 5 at a time.  Right now, I use the following traversal code which gets me ALL of the friends-of-friends at once (it can take so long that it will cause a timeout):

```
    nodes = @neo.traverse(user_node,"nodes", {"order" => "breadth first",
                                          "uniqueness" => "node global",
                                          "relationships" => {"type"=> "friends", "direction" => "all"},
                                          "return filter" => {
                                            "language" => "javascript",
                                            "body" => 
                                            "position.length() == 2;"},
                                          "depth" => 2})
```

From the neo4j website (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-traverse.html#rest-api-creating-a-paged-traverser), it looks like there is already such a thing as paged traversals, but I don't see any references to doing this from neography.

Could someone provide example code to show how to do this with neography if possible, how to do it without neography if necessary, or a work-around such as limiting the number of results returned from the example traversal I'm already doing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a Cypher query for this, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html, like

```
START n = node(0) Match n-[:friends]->()-[:friends]->fof RETURN fof SKIP 0 LIMIT 5
```

for the first 5 friends?

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to mostly work, with a few quirks.  I think it's returning both the original node as well as some direct friends.  Perhaps it's returning some direct friends who are also connected through another friend, but I thought this query should exclude direct friends?

Also, it seems to return no results (nil) when I specify a RETURN field that doesn't exist.  Is there a way to say "return this field if it exists, otherwise return the results with nil for that field"?  E.g. ... "->fof RETURN fof.uid, fof.name, fof.birthday SKIP 0 LIMIT 5"

Comment: I'm still wondering about it returning direct friends as well, but I fixed the issue with return fields that don't exist using the ? operator:
e.g. ... ->fof RETURN fof.uid, fof.name, fof.birthday? SKIP 0 LIMIT 5

Comment: After more investigation, I found a way to fix the issue of it returning both the start node and direct friends, while preserving the friends-of-friends that it returns.  I'm marking your answer as accepted, thanks!  Here's the cypher query I have working with those extra tweaks:

start n = node(1) match (n)-[:friends]->(friend)-[:friends]->fof where not(n<--fof) and (n.uid != fof.uid) return friend.uid, friend.name, fof.uid, fof.name, fof.gender? SKIP 0 LIMIT 5

Comment: Great, that's exactly the way.